# Keyboard shortcut to reveal onscreen keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, accessibility

Does someone know if it is possible to bind a command to a button which will reveal the onscreen keyboard? (Note: The onscreen keyboard has already be started.)

Currently when I want to reveal the onscreen keyboard, I have to click the keyboard icon in the tray bar. This is not very convenient mainly because the onscreen keyboard does not reveal itself when you are yet still focused on a text field. Hence I want to bind it to a button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can do that by creating a custom keyboard shortcut to the onscreen keyboard. The onscreen keyboard used in Ubuntu is Onboard.

Search for *Keyboard* and move to *Shortcuts* tab. Go to *Custom Shortcuts* and click the + button. After that a small dialog box will appear. Give an appropriate name to the shortcut and enter `onboard` in the command box. Then, press *Apply* button.

[image]

After saving it, click on *Disabled* and hold down the new shortcut key that you want to assign to the command.

[image]

After that, pressing the keyboard combination will pop up the onscreen keyboard.

Comment: Thank you @jokerdino. I ended up using another program, xbindkeys, to bind a shortcut. Because I wanted it to bind to a special key (hardware key), on my laptop.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. It looks like my answer is not the one you found useful. May I suggest you add your own solution and accept that instead? It would be really useful to those who would want to do it that way in the future. Thanks.

Comment: As said, I ended up using xbindkeys, you can then press a random key (also hardware ones) and it finds the correct "command" to activate that key. You can then bind a command to it. However it does not work anymore, at least for me, in Ubuntu 12.04, because it can't detect the hardware key anymore :(

Comment: Oh yes. You did. Nothing much to do otherwise then?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and using keyboard shortcuts, you can bind any key with these commands to show and hide the on-screen keyboard

I have bound F8 to show onboard

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.Show
```

I have bound F10 to hide onboard

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.Hide
```

Or you can bind just one key like F10 to toggle the onboard

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --print-reply --dest=org.onboard.Onboard /org/onboard/Onboard/Keyboard org.onboard.Onboard.Keyboard.ToggleVisible
```