# Having trouble reassigning keys

Tags: 14.04, dell

Trying to rebind keys so that I can use my Dell XPS 12 in tablet mode optimally.

1. Want to rebind the left Windows key and trick the system into thinking that it is the right windows key. This Dell has no right Windows key.
2. Want to rebind the left Windows key afterwards to be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (tilde key) so that I can assign it to bring up the onscreen keyboard. There is a built in shortcut: [Keyboard shortcut to reveal onscreen keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73667/keyboard-shortcut-to-reveal-onscreen-keyboard)

Racking my brain trying to solve this. Should take no more than 5 min for an expert to help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You would think this would be easy, but nothing involving the meta key (Windows key) on Linux is easy.

Comment: @dash-plus-java I've heavily rebound shortcuts using the Windows key (well, [Linux key](http://www.keyboardco.com/product/tux-penguin-logo-windows-keys-2-keycaps-for-cherry-mx-switches.asp) in my case). I'm using KDE, but it's certainly possible in Linux in general.

Answer (score 0):

5 min?  More like an entire day as you'd have to create your own keyboard mapping (=redefine entire keyboard).

If you drop request #1 and just want the "Super" key (not "Windows" key) to bring up an on-screen keyboard, you'd first have to

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case "super"
```

and redefine all the keys that use "Super" to use something else, then create the custom keyboard shortcut, define some temporary shortcut (like [Alt][Shift_L][Shift_R][Ctrl][W]) using the UI, then

```
gsettings list-recursively  | grep --ignore-case "[Alt][Shift_L][Shift_R][Ctrl][W]"
```

and then re-define using

```
gsettings set path_to_key "<Super>"
```

*That* would only take an hour or so...